# Json serializer reference handling asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When fetching data from a database, we have a lot of recursive and circular references. To handle this we configure the (default) json serializer to give the objects ids and refs, e.g..

```
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "Children": 
    [
      { "$id": "2", "Children": null, "Name": "Bob Smith", "Parent": { "$ref": "1" }},
      { "$id": "3", "Children": null, "Name": "Suzy Smith", "Parent": { "$ref": "1" }}
    ],
    "Name": "John Smith",
    "Parent": null
  },
  {
    "$ref": "2"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "3"
  }
]
```

**My question regards the behaviour of the $id and $ref numbers when there are a lot of requests**. We handle a decent amount of traffic and they would overflow fairly quickly.

We configure it as

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                 options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                 options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                 options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
                 });
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to perf test your code? I don't know how you expect people to know how your code will perform with so little information

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. I was asking about how "$id": "#" behaves when it reaches int.max, or whatever id is interpreted as. It is not a code-specific thing, it is part of the asp.net mvc.
You do not need to see any custom code for this, what I have provided is enough if you have the knowledge.

Comment: Fair enough, good luck getting an answer